# Concatenate a series of lists with incrementing numeric suffixes in R

Tags: r, list, concatenation

In R I have a series of lists with incrementing numeric suffixes eg mylist1 , mylist2 , mylist3.
I want to concatenate these , like c(mylist1, mylist2, mylist3)

Is there a shorthand way to manage this?

Comment: Please explain what you mean by "concatenate"

Comment: Or do you want to create one list by _merging_ the lists?

Comment: I don't want to merge. Append may be a better term than concatenate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are trying to create a list of lists.
You can do it simply by calling:

```
list(list1, list2, list3)
```

If you have many lists with a similar name pattern, you can select use `mget` to GET all objects whose names have a specific pattern, (`ls(pattern=x)`).

**data**

```
list8<-list(1,2)
list9<-list(3,4)
list10<-list(5,6)
#Included the lists with indexes 8:10 so that the importance of ordering by `parse_number(ls)` is highlighted. Without the `parse_number` step, the list would be sorted by names, with a different order
```

**Answer**

```
list_of_lists<-mget(ls(pattern = 'list\\d+')[order(parse_number(ls(pattern = 'list\\d+')))])

> str(list_of_lists)
List of 3
 $ mylist8:List of 2
  ..$ : num 1
  ..$ : num 2
 $ mylist9:List of 2
  ..$ : num 3
  ..$ : num 4
 $ mylist10:List of 2
  ..$ : num 5
  ..$ : num 6
```

Comment: Thanks. mget does the job to produce a list of lists, but I was looking to concatenate by appending the lists together.  So using your example I wanted c(list8, list9, list 10) , producing  a list of 6 objects.
I could do the second step of `unlist (list_of_lists, recursive = F)` to get what I was after, but still interested to see if there is a one step process

Comment: Another base option which still uses the interim step of creating a list of lists would be to use `Reduce (append,  mget(paste0("list", c(8:10))))`, but I am still curious to know if there is a way without creating the interim list of lists

Comment: The methos you describe seem simple enough, what else could you find there?